# concatenate two index values in for each

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loop like this

```
$rr=array();

foreach($relations as $key=>$type){
  $rr[$relationType->U2U_Related_USR_ID]=$type[$k]->MSTT_Name.' / '.$type[$k+1]->MSTT_Name;
  $k++;
}
```

Am getting only first index value. how to concatenate two index values in for each.

Comment: It is not clear what the index should be and what the value should be.  Please give an example of what should be concatenated in the index.

Comment: **Please review and approve an answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Increment by **2** !

```
$rr = array();

for ($i = 0, $n = count($type); $i < $n; $i += 2) {
    $t1 = $type[$i];
    $t2 = $type[$i + 1];
    $rr[$relationType->U2U_Related_USR_ID] = $t1->MSTT_Name.' / '.$t2->MSTT_Name;
}
```

**Note:** `$type`'s length should be an even number!

Answer (score 0):

you can work with 2 couples key/value inside your loop like this :

```
foreach($relations as $key=>$type){

    list( $odd_key, $odd_value ) = each( $relations );

    //... your code here

    // This work with a step by 2 elements. If you need step by 1,
    // add the following line at the end of the loop :

    //prev( $relations )
}
```